# Svn Log still shows result even after update of WC

Tags: svn

Subversion(svn.exe)
I have made a svn commit. Performed the Svn update on my working copy. Now I perform :

```
$svn log -r HEAD
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r14478 | Paul, Ajo | 2013-09-02 21:36:04 +0530 (Mon, 02 Sep 2013) | 1 line

dummy checking 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Even `$svn log -r 14478` gives me the same output.

My expectation was after I had performed an svn up on the WC, when I run svn log, I should not see any more changes. Am I doing it wrong? Basically I was using `svn log -r HEAD` as a way to check if the working copy is older than URL copy. The result will be parsed in an ant script.

This is my first question, so pardon me if I have broken any rules.

Comment: are you not misunderstanding with svn diff ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I should have tried svn diff with various options for my result. right now, @nosid 's answer works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command shows all commit logs since the last update. However, the range is *inclusive*. That means, even if you have updated to the most recent revision (`BASE`==`HEAD`), you will see the log message of this revision.

```
svn log -r HEAD:BASE
```

You can use the following command to show the difference between the revision of your working copy and the most recent revision. If your working copy is up-to-date, the output will be empty:

```
svn diff -r HEAD:BASE
```

See the section about [Revision Keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) in the online book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) for more information.